# How can I move or replicate my Apple Music iTunes Cloud Library to Spotify?

Tags: itunes, icloud, apple-music, macos, spotify

I have been using Apple Music from day 1, but I'm disappointed and want to move back to Spotify. Is there any way at all to easily replicate or move my entire library from Apple Music to Spotify?

All solutions I encountered by searching the internet only work the other way around.

Comment: Does this [help page](https://support.spotify.com/uk/learn-more/guides/#!/article/listen-to-local-files) @ Spotify not give you enough information?

Comment: [Soundiiz](https://soundiiz.com/) might do the trick, though it looks like the service is playlist rather than library based, meaning that you'd have to export your library as a playlist file.

Comment: 1st hit on Google. https://freeyourmusic.com

Answer (score 1):

Though I haven't used it personally, the online service [Stamp](https://freeyourmusic.com) claims that it will transfer your "tracks and playlists across various services," including Spotify and Apple Music in either direction.

It looks like, assuming you want to move more than a handful of songs, it costs €9 for a license. Reading through the iTunes and Play Store reviews for the mobile versions, it looks like most of the negative reviews are just people who didn't realize it's not free, though some people say that it's fairly slow or doesn't do a very good job of matching up the tracks between services.